# Converting scientific notation to fixed notation in java using DecimalFormat

Tags: java

Is there any way to convert scientific notation to fixed notation in Java.
Currently I have got the following code:

```
DecimalFormat dfmt=new DecimalFormat("######:#######");
print(dfmt.format((new BigDecimal((Math.pow(10,-3)*3000),MathContext.Decimal64)).stripTrailingZero()));
```

The above code does converts scientific notation to fixed notation,however if the result is greater than zero the decimal place is ignored. 
In the above example it prints 3; instead of 3.0

Comment: why not just use `toPlainString()` of `BigDecimal`?

Comment: @Nim He wanted it to end with `.0`... `toPlainString()` will remove decimals if zero.

Comment: This isn't 'converting scientific notation to fixed notation'. There is no scientific notation here. It is (1) constructing a BigDecimal *value* and (2) *formatting* that value into decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the the pattern `0.0`:

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("12345678901234567890"); // large integer
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("0.0").format(d));
```

Outputs (in my locale):

```
12345678901234567890.0
```